# python mariadb connector error when fetching results from a DATETIME with value NULL

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

Well i guess something is not right with the mariadb connector...

I have a table row that looks like this:

| id | title | category | date_posted | date_due | content | file | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | test 7 | 10 | 2021-04-01 21:50:21 |  | content 7 | strawsf9cdaf.txt | 16 |

The problem is that i have a DATETIME field that is NULL (the date_due date is not mandatory in my app)

It seems that after passing values to the execute() method, the fetchall() method parses returned data differently.

First case works great
Second returns the "ValueError: year 0 is out of range"

```
id=("6",)
statement1 = "select * from posts where id = 6"
statement2 = "select * from posts where id = ?"

db.cursor.execute(statement1)
result = db.cursor.fetchall()
for x in result:
     print(x)

db.cursor.execute(statement2, id)
result = db.cursor.fetchall()
for x in result:
     print(x)
```

I tried to list() the connector - same result

I tried to change values and table column attributes - same result

I though its a problem of versions so i updated to latest python, mariadb server and python connector (on ubuntu 20.04)- same result

The result:

```
6, 'test 7', 10, datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 21, 50, 21), None, 'content 7', 'strawsf9cdaf.txt', 16)
ValueError: year 0 is out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/project dir/main_test3.py", line 38, in <module>
    result = db.cursor.fetchall()
SystemError: <method 'fetchall' of 'mariadb.connection.cursor' objects> returned a result with an error set

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: That certainly looks like a connector bug to me.

Comment: how do i report that? is it better to just switch to mysql connector :D i scratched my head over this some days already 0.o

Comment: There's a "Contact Us" page on the https://mariadb.com page.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in MariaDB Connector/Python and recently fixed by myself. Fix will be available in next version (1.0.7).

Date "0000-00-00" is not valid in Python and therefore had to be converted to None instead.

Thanks for your report.